# Calculating form values using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a php generated form code:

```
echo "<td><select id='num".$result['id']."' name='num".$result['id']."'>
      <option value='1'>1</option>
      <option value='2'>2</option>
      <option value='3'>3</option>
      <option value='4'>4</option>
      <option value='5'>5</option>
      <option value='6'>6</option>
      <option value='7'>7</option>
      <option value='8'>8</option>
      <option value='9'>9</option>
      <option value='10'>10</option>
      </select>
      </td>";
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' value='".$result['sell_price']."'                    name='".$result['id']."' id='".$result['id']."' /></td>";
```

As you see the value of the select box is already defined and the value for the checkbox is obtained from the database.

I want to calculate the values of the checkbox and product the sum with the value of the selectbox using jquery. 
I have this function to "onclick on any td the checkbox is selected" :

```
$(function () {
    $("td").on(\'click\', function (e) {
        if (! $(e.target).closest(\'select\').length ) {
           var tr  = $(this).closest("tr"),
               chk = tr.find("input[type=\'checkbox\']").get(0);
           if (e.target != chk) {
               chk.checked = !chk.checked;
           }
           if ( tr.find("input[type=\'checkbox\']").is(":checked")) {
               tr.css("font-weight", "bold");
           } else {
               tr.css("font-weight", "");
           }
        }
    });  
});
```

Any help please?

Comment: Why are you escaping your single quotes? Besides that, what problem are you actually having?  Do you get errors in console? Are you getting unexpected values?  can you put your code into a fiddle for easier testing?

Comment: becuse i'm writing it on php echo command

Comment: It might help to show you actual javascript source output and your HTML source.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to calculate the sum of all selected check box then

```
 function calculata() {         
     var sum=0;
     $('#your_div_Id :checked').each(function() {
       sum=sum+($(this).val());
     });
  }
```

if you want an array of  values

```
var values = $('input:checkbox:checked.group1').map(function () {
  return this.value;
}).get(); // ["10", "11", "07"]
```

Comment: 1) changed #your_div_Id with yours ? 2)tried alert(sum); after sum=sum+($(this).val());   3)called calculata()?

Comment: yes ,,
bro just edit my js code to me ..
i have a table without id ,, and all information u need is here .
also i wanna product the sum on the select box value